# .cmake : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x1B1

Tags: opencv, cmake, visual-studio-2017

am trying to build a `openCV` application in `c++` using `VisualStudio2017`

debugging gives me the following error:

```
 C:\opencv\build\install\x64\vc15\lib\OpenCVConfig-version.cmake 
 : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x1B1 `
```

i used the following link for installation 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdeP8SdvSJw

i did refer to the different answers on this topic here. but, couldn't find the solution regarding `cmake`.

Comment: you must have configured/installed VisualStudio and Opencv incorrectly... see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43786856/982161)

Comment: Hi sir! Did you solve the problem? I have also have the same problem, with QT. Thanks!