# unable to install OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi guys really new to Visual Studio 2017 and im trying to get openCV into it to play around with the stuff, tried following the instructions from this [How to can I install/configure OpenCV3.2.0 with Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786856/how-to-can-i-install-configure-opencv3-2-0-with-visual-studio-2017)

but my cmake keeps showing the error that the cmakelist is not in the folder, not sure what i should do any ideas?

Comment: CMake Error: The source directory "C:/_OpenCv3/opencv" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: not sure if im doing anything wrong too

Comment: but where is the CMake list located??

Comment: theres one in there openCV master folder and one more in the CMake 3.82 folder, not sure which one i should use and where to put it

Comment: tried one of it and this is the error it showed :CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    cmake/OpenCVMinDepVersions.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:113 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:116 (ocv_update):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_update".

Comment: use the one from master folder because that is the branch with the code

Comment: ok so do i put the one from the master folder into the opencv folder?

Comment: nope, put the path to it in cmake

Comment: showing this error CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    cmake/OpenCVMinDepVersions.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:113 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:116 (ocv_update):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_update".
 
think its the same as the one up top

Comment: ok sorry one sec

Comment: yeah still showing the same errors D: sorry man
still rly confused over this

Comment: thanks for the help... managed to get it in now trying to fix the build problems and stuff...wondering, if you could help me out

Comment: are you using VS2017?

Comment: yeap its the free version though.....for students...dont know if it has differences compared to the paid versions and stuff

Comment: doesnt matter, it works!

Comment: ok i seem to be getting errors though after i debug the thing....going to re-do the process

Comment: compiling a list of errors now

Comment: For steps 9 & 10)

(Debug conf -> Build -> Build ->All Build
Error: 18>Done building project "opencv_hdf.vcxproj" -- FAILED.)

(Release Conf -> Build -> Build -> All Build
Error line: 18>Done building project "opencv_hdf.vcxproj" -- FAILED.)

(Debug Conf ->Build -> Build ->Install
Error Message: 3>Done building project "opencv_hdf.vcxproj" -- FAILED.)

(Release Conf ->Build ->Build ->install
Error Message: 1>Done building project "opencv_hdf.vcxproj" -- FAILED.)
@ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. I just comment   `# ocv_update(CUDA_LINK_LIBRARIES_KEYWORD "PRIVATE")` in the file `cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake`