# OpenCV ALL_BUILDS not found VS

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to create a C++ program using openCV on Windows.
I followed these instructions: [How can I install/configure OpenCV3.2.0 with C++, Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786856/how-can-i-install-configure-opencv3-2-0-with-c-visual-studio-2017) (I can't comment because of the reputation)

I completed all the steps and when I compile the project as they say to do, everything works but when I try to run it I got the following error:

C:\openCV\build\Debug\ALL_BUILD not found

Do you know why?

Comment: Set the startup project to the one that generates the executable you want to run. ALL_BUILD is just an empty project that depends on everything else, so that you can build everything in one shot.

Comment: And how should I generate this executable? I have a cpp file but I don't know where I am supposed to put it.