# Opencv 4.3.0 installation Windows Error: vs_version.rc : No such file or directory?

Tags: windows, qt, opencv

I'll install Opencv 4.3.0. But I'm getting the errors.
Opencv Cmake Flags:
cmake -D OPENCV_ENABLE_ALLOCATOR_STATS=OFF -D OPENCV_ALLOCATOR_STATS_COUNTER_TYPE = int64_t -D WITH_MFMS=OFF  -D WITH_IPP=OFF -D WITH_TBB=OFF  -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -D WITH_QT=ON ..

Error: vs_version.rc : No such file or directory.

How can i solve the problem ?

Thanks,

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43786856/982161

Answer (score 0):

according to the bug reported in the official repository [here:](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16990) you need to set this param

```
-DOPENCV_ALLOCATOR_STATS_COUNTER_TYPE=int64_t
```

Comment: This parameter already exists. I looked at the same link too. But i still get an error.